Size of pyarrow Table in bytes
I have a basic pyarrow.Table. What's the best way to get it's size in bytes?
Here is an example table:
import pyarrow as pa

n_legs = pa.array([2, 4, 5, 100])
animals = pa.array(["Flamingo", "Horse", "Brittle stars", "Centipede"])
names = ["n_legs", "animals"]    
table = pa.table([n_legs, animals], names=names)


You can tell the get_total_buffer_size() method on various PyArrow objects which will return the total size of the object's underlying buffers in bytes:
So in your example, this would be:
import pyarrow as pa

n_legs = pa.array([2, 4, 5, 100])
animals = pa.array(["Flamingo", "Horse", "Brittle stars", "Centipede"])
names = ["n_legs", "animals"]    
table = pa.table([n_legs, animals], names=names)

table.get_total_buffer_size()

Which produces 87.
